# Trying to identify SMD component from a Ps2 Slimline

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount, fuses

*(English isn't my first language)* I'm trying to fix an old **Playstation 2 Slim** my cousin had that was turning off by itself after 5 minutes playing. After some search on the internet, I found that it was a common overheating problem coused by the cooler fan not spinning, wich could be caused by two things: *1) The cooler is broken;* *2) **There's a sacrificial SMD component in the motherboard tagged PS17 that burned**.*

After quite some time I was able to fix and test the cooler, but it still wasn't spinning when plugged in the console, so I knew it had to be the **SMD component**. I tested it with a multimeter, and indeed it failed the continuity test. I saw in a video someone saying it was a ***"fusible resistor"***. I'm trying to identify it so I can search for some scrap component that could replace it or perhaps buy another one, but I wasn't able to find anything useful in the internet. *It appears have a width between 1mm and 2mm.*

The Ps2 is a **9000X series** and I wasn't able to find any service manuals. I have a pretty amateur knowledge in electronics and this is getting me frustrated. I wonder if someone can help me.

***(07/07/2020) Edit:*** I did more research and also ended up in this post: [Please help me identify the SMD component in the picture (or help me fix my Wacom)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223792/please-help-me-identify-the-smd-component-in-the-picture-or-help-me-fix-my-waco). So it's probably a SMD Fuse marked "***MD***". I still wasn't able to identify it.

[image: The SMD component]

Answer (score 1):

I found this datasheet online from *NIC Components* that gave me some matching information:
https://www.niccomp.com/products/catalog/nfcc_nfhc.pdf.

Tells that the component would be **package 0603** and have a "***MD***" marking.

[image: Part Number: NFCC06 132ADTPF, Package: 0603, Marking Symbol: MD]

Since 0603 packages are 1.5-1.6mm wide, I took measures again, and considering human error it is possible that the component is indeed 0603.

I'm not 100% sure, because the one I have is burned up, so I can't measure its properties with a multimeter.

Sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: That seems reasonable to me. Looks like it's a fuse that you could replace, but fuses blowing is often indicative of a fault elsewhere on the board; after all, the job of a fuse is to blow when there's too much current, and the easiest way for there to be too much current is for a fault to occur.